# Move data to new ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found and Modified some code to do want i want and it works but now its just a Beast and i know there is a Better/Cleaner way to do this - We will have 10-20 working this sheet throughout the day and i just do not want it to get bogged down so much

I have attache the Code.gs file and here is a link to the Google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15j4sdwvQfVUrDbr_35Iof5ZV0peSu3Jm3XlWgkB7CXw/edit?usp=sharing

Part 1 - This part of this code is to leave a time-stamp with the current users email and Date and time in the two column next to it -

```
function onEdit(event) {

      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//-----------------Your-Sheet 8-----------   

   if( s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 8" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

//-----------When data is entered in column F (the 6 column) it will automatically 
//    insert the current users Email in column G and will put a Time-Stamp in column H

    if( r.getColumn() == 8) { //use getRow for row and getColumn for column 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);//offset (row,column)
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(Session.getUser());//inserts current users email     
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);//offset (row,column)
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
         nextCell.setValue(new Date());//will only put date, format "123/Date and time" if time needed
    }
  }


//-----------------Your-Sheet 7-----------   
   if( s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 7" ) { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() == 8) { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
        nextCell.setValue(Session.getUser());
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
         nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

 So on and so on 
//-----------------Your-Sheet 6-----------     

//-----------------Your-Sheet 5-----------     

//-----------------Your-Sheet 4-----------   

//-----------------Your-Sheet 3-----------   

//-----------------Your-Sheet 2-----------   

//-----------------Your-Sheet 1-----------
```

> ????----Is there a way to do something like  -   if( s.getName() ==
>   "All" ) {   - Or getactivesheet? i'm just not sure -----????

Part 2 - This is the beast part of the code i'm really hoping there is a way to clean this up and make it more compact and run better.

```
//------------------------------------Move Row to another Sheet--------------------------------------------


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Checks to see what sheet the user is on 
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();


//---------------Your-Sheet 1 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 1" to desired Sheet--------------  

//  if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" ---- (checks what sheet the user is on)
//  && r.getColumn() == 15 ---- (This is the Column number that is being looked at i.e. column 13 = Column M)
//  && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 7") ---- (the value in this cell determines what or where this data is going) 
    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 7") {
        var row = r.getRow(); //This is selecting the active row
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); //This tells how many column are in that row that have data i.e. if the last column with data is column "R" there is no need to copy the data all the way to column "Z" 
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 7"); // This is what sheet we want our row of data to be sent to 
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); //This checks to find the last row with data and targets the row below 
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); // This Copies data to the empty row we just found 
        s.deleteRow(row); // This deletes the row off of the current sheet 
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 3") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 3");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 4") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 4");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 5") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 5");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
        }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 6") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 6");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 8") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 8");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 1" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 2") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 2");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }


//---------------Your-Sheet 2 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 2" to desired Sheet--------------  

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 7") {
        var row = r.getRow(); 
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); 
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 7");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); 
        s.deleteRow(row); 
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 3") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 3");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 4") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 4");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 5") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 5");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
        }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 6") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 6");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 8") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 8");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
    if(s.getName() == "Your-Sheet 2" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Your-Sheet 1") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your-Sheet 1");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }

And i have to do this for every Sheet!

//---------------Your-Sheet 3 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 3" to desired Sheet--------------  

//---------------Your-Sheet 4 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 4" to desired Sheet--------------   

//---------------Your-Sheet 5 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 5" to desired Sheet

//---------------Your-Sheet 6 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 6" to desired Sheet--------------  

//---------------Your-Sheet 7 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 7" to desired Sheet--------------  

//---------------Your-Sheet 8 - Moving select Row from "Your-Sheet 8" to desired Sheet--------------  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, as long as you want to check all sheets, you should be able to just leave out the outer
`if( s.getName() == "Your-Sheet #" )`

For the second one, try this:

```
if(r.getColumn() == 15) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(r.getValue());
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

I tested that on the sheet you linked and it worked for me.

Comment: This works Great!! Thank you!! if i have other questions is it better to post a new question or comment in here? I want to know how to do the Search better then how i have it. right now i am using this code on the sheet '=if(vlookup(B3,'Your-Sheet 1'!$B:$B,1,false),MATCH(B3,'Your-Sheet 1'!$B:$B,0))'

Comment: Yes, that would be best as a new question. I guarantee you can do the search differently, that query makes no sense. You're saying to look for the value from B3 in the current sheet, in the B column in Sheet1, and return the value in the same cell that is found. If that value is true, then return the position of that value.  

Link your other question here when you post it.

Comment: hey thank you so much for your help on this. here is the link to the search question: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206840/add-search-to-google-spreadsheet-using-script/52207377#52207377

Answer (score 0):

First, this should be broken into two questions.

For timestamps, you don't need to run the code on each individual sheet - it will run for the entire workbook. Also, you're passing an `event` object into `onEdit` but you're not actually using. The first bit is to get the active cell from the event object rather than using a bunch of `if` statements.

**Update information on edit**

```js
// To access the user email string, you have to use an installable trigger through the GUI.
function onUpdate(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); // Get the edited sheet and cells
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  // If it was column H edited...
  if(col == 8) {

    // Set the editor's email and a timestamp
    sheet.getRange(row, col).offset(0, 1, 1, 2).setValues([ [e.user.getEmail().toString(), new Date] ]);
  }
}
```